# codeigniter pass value of emailfunction from controller to view?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to pass the string from controller to view.  So I write $data['emailstr]  and ['emailfail']  like this in If-Else clause in Controller page

```
                $this->load->library('email', array('mailtype'=>'html'));//default mailtype is 'text'
                $this->email->from('supanat_thana@hotmail.com', "Webmaster");
                $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
                $this->email->subject("Confirm your account");
                $message = "<p>Thank you for register!</p>";
                $message .= "<p><a href='".base_url()."register/activate_user'>Click Here</a> To Activate your Account </p>";
                $this->email->message($message);



                    if($this->email->send())
                    {
                        $data['emailstr'] = "email has been sent";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $data['emailfail'] = "could not send the email.";
                    }



                $this->load->view('regislogin/success', $data);
```

But in the viewpage, I can write the success string email sent  but has error occur on $emailfail string  : Undefined variable: emailfail

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Register </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
        echo "<h3>Thank you for your registration</h3>";
        echo $emailstr."<br/><br/>";
        if($emailfail != null) {echo $emailfail."<br/><br/>";} else{}
        echo anchor('home', 'กลับสู่หน้าหลัก');

?>
</body>
</html>
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is because:

```
if($this->email->send())
{
    $data['emailstr'] = "email has been sent";
}
else
{
    $data['emailfail'] = "could not send the email.";
}
```

> $data['emailstr'] & $data['emailfail']

are uninitialized if your outer if condition do not success. I  think that's happen with your case.

Comment: Yes but if I didnot write ['emailfail'] string  ..., when it actually fail , it did not have message "could not send the email" so I try to write them both

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset()` instead of `!=null`. You can't run a comparison on a value that doesn't exist, but `isset()` determines if a variable is **set** and is not `NULL`.

```
if(isset($emailfail)) {echo $emailfail."<br/><br/>";} else{}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending string send array like below and check

```
$key = md5(uniqid());
$this->load->library('email', array('mailtype'=>'html'));//default mailtype is 'text'
$this->email->from('supanat_thana@hotmail.com', "Webmaster");
$this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
$this->email->subject("Confirm your account");
$message = "<p>Thank you for register!</p>";
$message .= "<p><a href='".base_url()."register/activate_user/$key'>Click Here</a> To Activate your Account </p>";

$this->email->message($message);
            if($this->register_model->add_temp_user($key))
            {
                if($this->email->send())
                {
                    $data['emailstatus'] =   "success"; 
                    $data['emailstr'] =   "email has been sent";
                }
                else
                {
                    $data['emailstatus'] =   "fail";
                    $data['emailfail'] = "could not send the email.";
                }
            }
            $this->load->view('regislogin/success', $data);
```

In View check emailstatus like below

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Register </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
   <?php
   if($this->input->post("btn"))
   {
        echo "<h3>Thank you for your registration</h3>";
        echo $emailstr."<br/><br/>";
        if($emailstatus != "success") {echo $emailfail."<br/><br/>";} else{}
        echo anchor('home', 'กลับสู่หน้าหลัก');
   }else{
        echo "<h3>เข้าสู่ระบบแล้ว</h3>";
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
        echo "</pre>";
        echo anchor('login/logout', 'Logout')."<br/>"; 
        echo anchor('home', 'กลับสู่หน้าหลัก');
   }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we should "assign different value to the same variable" instead of naming two different variables.

```
if($this->email->send())
{
    $data['message'] = "email has been sent";
}
else
{
    $data['message'] = "could not send the email.";
}
```

Also, I think later you might want to use session flash data. It would be convenient to use flash data for displaying information like your example.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('msg_to_display',$data['message']);
redirect('/your/controller');
```

And in View page, it could be accessed by

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('msg_to_display'); ?>
```

The point is it set the message in the session after redirect, but once you refresh the page, the message is already gone.

Learn more in [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?#flashdata)